# How to translate text without auto translate magento

Tags: magento2

I have a text after installing a payment module which I can not translate in any way. I have opened the magento translator but it does not include this text. How can I translate this?
[image]

EDIT2:
I have added translate line to pl_PL.csv in payment module use notepad:

```
"Pay using Masterpass","Zapłać kartą Masterpass"
```

Then I refresh page and no see any result.

Of course before refresh, I run some command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Impossible edit name in backend:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Use apache open office calc to edit the CSV files. That should solve it :)

Comment: @Bare Feet now this error solved but after upgrade system no see any result :(

Comment: It's probably because the text is not wrapped in the translate function `__()`. Are you not able to change the title in the Admin Payment Config?

Comment: Have a look at that also: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

Comment: @Bare Feet in old module version I can change  payment method title but now in new version I cannot see this.  I have update my topic to show you.

Comment: That's basic configuration settings, are there any advanced configuration settings?

Comment: I have also added screen from advanced settings.

Comment: That's well strange... Try to find the phrase "Pay using Masterpass" in the module and see if it has translation function. If not, then add it and the csv file should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate new text you can add text and its translation in module language csv file like this :

```
'Your Text here','Your translation here'
```

However in templates the left side text should be defined using magento translator function like this :

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Your Text here') ?>
```

Comment: I have installed language pack from GitHub via composer. Where is located .csv file language ? https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-pl_pl

Comment: Ok I have founded language pack.

Comment: Great, just add your new text translation in relevant file ( if you have module installed then there should be translation file too there you can add translated text)

Comment: I have add new translate line to .csv file in language pack in module and I see error. Please check I update my topic.

Comment: There would be some encoding issue while adding text in translation file, use notepad to update the file

Comment: I have update my topic. Can you check ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the payment method names in **Admin > Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Payment methods > [Payment method name]**

You should be able to change the name of the payment method in the "Title" row.

You are able to set the title of the payment method as per **store view** scope.

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to use the translation `.csv` method.

You can translate the text using the language csv file like this :

> 'Original text','Your translation'

NOTE:

The text need to be wraped in the Magento translation function:

```
__('Original text')
```

---

I still believe changing the text in the admin is by far easiest option.

Comment: Thanks for your try help but impossible to change  name payment method in backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change it in Admin Payment Config section or else tryout in translation csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use theme translation **CSV** file if you are using custom theme.

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html